# Pyplot, plot 2 dataset into one figure, skip part of the y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting to different datasets into one graph with pylab.plot(), which works great. But one dataset has values between 0% an 25% and the other has values between 75% and 100%. I want to skip 30% to 70% on the y-axis to save some space.  Do you have any suggestions how this might be work with pyplot?

EDIT:

For clearness I added the following graphic. I want to skip 30% to 60% on the y axis, so that the red line and the green line come closer together.

[image: graphic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is based on Space_C0wb0ys post.

```
fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot( range(1,10), camean - 25, 'ro-' )
ax.plot( range(1,10), oemean , 'go-' )
ax.plot( range(1,10), hlmean , 'bo-' ) 
ax.set_yticks(range(5, 60, 5))
ax.set_yticklabels(["5","10","15","20","25","30","...","65","70","75"]) 
ax.legend(('ClassificationAccuracy','One-Error','HammingLoss'),loc='upper right')
pylab.show()
```

This code creates the following graphic.[image]

Comment: My solution obviously was not correct. Since you found a correct solution yourself, you can also accept that. This is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could subtract 40 from the x-values for your second functions to make the range of x-values continuous. This would give you a range from 0% to 70%. Then you can make set the tics and labes of the x-axis as follows:

```
x_ticks = range(71, 0, 10)
a.set_xticks(x_ticks)
a.set_xticklabels([str(x) for x in [0, 10, 20, 30, 70, 80, 90, 100]])
```

Where `a` is the current axes. So basically, you plot your functions in the range from 0% to 70%, but label the axis with a gap.

To illustrate - the following script:

```
from numpy import arange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = arange(0, 26) # first function
y1 = x1**2

x2 = arange(75, 100) # second function
y2 = x2*4 + 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x1, y1)
ax.plot(x2 - 40, y2) # shift second function 40 to left
ax.set_xticks(range(0, 61, 5)) # set custom x-ticks
# set labels for x-ticks - labels have the gap we want
ax.set_xticklabels([str(x) for x in range(0, 26, 5) + range(70, 101, 5)])
plt.show()
```

Produces the following plot (note the x-labels):

[image: Output of script above]

Answer (score 0):

The matplotlib documentation actually has [an example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html) of how to do this.

The basic idea is to break up the plotting into two subplots, putting the same graph on each plot, then change the axes for each one to only show the specific part, then make it look nicer.

So, let's apply this. Imagine this is your starting code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random, math

# Generates data
i = range(10)
x = [math.floor(random.random() * 5) + 67 for i in range(10)]
y = [math.floor(random.random() * 5) + 22 for i in range(10)]
z = [math.floor(random.random() * 5) + 13 for i in range(10)]

# Original plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(i, x, 'ro-')
ax.plot(i, y, 'go-')
ax.plot(i, z, 'bo-')

plt.show()
```

[image: Starting point]

And we went to make it so that `x` is shown split off from the rest.

First, we want to plot the same graph twice, one on top of the other. To do this, the plotting function needs to be generic. Now it should look something like this:

```py
# Plotting function
def plot(ax):
    ax.plot(i, x, 'ro-')
    ax.plot(i, y, 'go-')
    ax.plot(i, z, 'bo-')

# Draw the graph on two subplots
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
plot(ax1)
plot(ax2)
```

[image: Two subplots of the same graph]

Now this seems worse, but we can change the range for each axis to focus on what we want. For now I'm just choosing easy ranges that I know will capture all the data, but I'll focus on making the axes equal later.

```py
# Changes graph axes
ax1.set_ylim(65, 75) # Top graph
ax2.set_ylim(5, 30) # Bottom graph
```

[image: Subplots with altered axes]

This is getting closer to what we're looking for. Now we need to just make it look a little nicer:

```py
# Hides the spines between the axes
ax1.spines.bottom.set_visible(False)
ax2.spines.top.set_visible(False)
ax1.xaxis.tick_top()
ax1.tick_params(labeltop=False)  # Don't put tick labels at the top
ax2.xaxis.tick_bottom()

# Adds slanted lines to axes
d = .5  # proportion of vertical to horizontal extent of the slanted line
kwargs = dict(
    marker=[(-1, -d), (1, d)],
    markersize=12,
    linestyle='none',
    color='k',
    mec='k',
    mew=1,
    clip_on=False
)
ax1.plot([0, 1], [0, 0], transform=ax1.transAxes, **kwargs)
ax2.plot([0, 1], [1, 1], transform=ax2.transAxes, **kwargs)
```

[image: Broken lines]

Finally, let's fix the axes. Here you need to do a little math and decide more on the layout. For instance, maybe we want to make the top graph smaller, since the bottom graph has two lines. To do that, we need to change the height ratios for the subplots, like so:

```py
# Draw the graph on two subplots
# Bottom graph is twice the size of the top one
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 2]})
```

[image: Resized subplots]

Finally, It's a good idea to make the axes match. In this case, because the bottom image is twice the size of the top one, we need to change the axes of one to reflect that. I've chosen to modify the top one in this time. The bottom graph covers a range of 25, which means the top one should cover a range of 12.5.

```py
# Changes graph axes
ax1.set_ylim(60.5, 73) # Top graph
ax2.set_ylim(5, 30) # Bottom graph
```

[image: Final graph]

This looks good enough to me. You can play around more with the axes or tick labels if you don't want the ticks to overlap with the broken lines.

Final code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random, math

# Generates data
i = range(10)
x = [math.floor(random.random() * 5) + 67 for i in range(10)]
y = [math.floor(random.random() * 5) + 22 for i in range(10)]
z = [math.floor(random.random() * 5) + 13 for i in range(10)]

# Plotting function
def plot(ax):
    ax.plot(i, x, 'ro-')
    ax.plot(i, y, 'go-')
    ax.plot(i, z, 'bo-')

# Draw the graph on two subplots
# Bottom graph is twice the size of the top one
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 2]})
plot(ax1)
plot(ax2)

# Changes graph axes
ax1.set_ylim(60.5, 73) # Top graph
ax2.set_ylim(5, 30) # Bottom graph

# Hides the spines between the axes
ax1.spines.bottom.set_visible(False)
ax2.spines.top.set_visible(False)
ax1.xaxis.tick_top()
ax1.tick_params(labeltop=False)  # Don't put tick labels at the top
ax2.xaxis.tick_bottom()

# Adds slanted lines to axes
d = .5  # proportion of vertical to horizontal extent of the slanted line
kwargs = dict(
    marker=[(-1, -d), (1, d)],
    markersize=12,
    linestyle='none',
    color='k',
    mec='k',
    mew=1,
    clip_on=False
)
ax1.plot([0, 1], [0, 0], transform=ax1.transAxes, **kwargs)
ax2.plot([0, 1], [1, 1], transform=ax2.transAxes, **kwargs)

plt.show()
```